# Can't boot with OSS kernel

Tags: xiaomi, kernel, android-11, android-12, miui-13

When booting with self-compiled kernel, this error appears in console-ramoops:

```
[   36.154875]  (6)[5679:idmap2]WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 5679 at fs/buffer.c:1154 __ext4_handle_dirty_super+0x50/0x1a8
[   36.154878]  (6)[5679:idmap2]Modules linked in: wlan_drv_gen4m ffffff85abf31000           (null) 2428928 0 (O) wmt_chrdev_wifi ffffff85a91b6000           (null) 32768 0 (O) gps_drv ffffff85a918e000           (null) 126976 0 (O) fmradio_drv ffffff85a9131000           (null) 299008 0 (O) bt_drv ffffff85a911e000           (null) 49152 0 (O) wmt_drv ffffff85a8f8c000           (null) 1376256 0 (O) fpsgo ffffff85a8ec0000           (null) 815104 0 (PO)
[   36.154894] -(6)[5679:idmap2]CPU: 6 PID: 5679 Comm: idmap2 Tainted: P S      W  O    4.14.186-perf-g7df73a1af183 #1
```

The full error file is at https://pastebin.com/LKUK9yvx
And the kernel itself is at https://github.com/camellian-devs/kernel_xiaomi_camellia